# HOW DO I GET RID OF THIS ERROR? <type> expected, got 'number'

Tags: sql, mysql, datagrip

I am trying to run an SQL database on my M1 Mac using MySQL and JetBrains Datagrip. I got Datagrip connected to my SQL but when I put my code in I get this strange error when I try to CREATE a table  **expected, got 'number'** or  **expected, got 'varchar2'**. This code runs perfectly in Oracle LiveSQL and I cannot figure out what this error means and how to fix it.

Datagrips suggests I "change my SQL dialect" but I don't know what that means or what that would do.

Any ideas on how to fix an error like this? Here is a screenshot of my Mac.[image]

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Answer (score 3):

`number` is not [a valid numeric datatype in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html).

`varchar2` is not [a valid string datatype in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html), either.

> This code runs perfectly in Oracle LiveSQL

Assuming Oracle LiveSQL itself runs SQL code in an Oracle RDBMS instance, this in no way means that it will be at all valid in an entirely different RDBMS.

Comment: This is correct.  SQL Servers from various vendors all run unique "flavors" or SQL.  Oracle is notoriously non-standard.